# zend http client programming issue with authentication

Tags: zend-framework

Is there any way to store Zend_Http_Client::AUTH_BASIC in a variable (like I've done with username and password) and use only the variable instead of the whole Zend_Http_Client::AUTH_BASIC??

Here's the snippet:

```
$client->setAuth($this->username, $this->password, Zend_Http_Client::AUTH_BASIC);
```